# Longest chain of last word of line/first word of next

Tags: python, optimization

Okay, so I am trying to find from a text file the longest chain in which the last word of one line is the first word of the next  (works well for poetry). The Python script I have to far works well but still takes an immensely long time. I am no coding expert and have really no idea of optimization. Am I running through more options than necessary? 
How can I reduce the time it takes to run through a longer text?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

# Opening the source text
with open("/text.txt") as g:
    all_lines = g.readlines()

def last_word(particular_line):
    if particular_line != "\n": 
        particular_line = re.sub(ur'^\W*|\W*$', "",particular_line)
        if len(particular_line) > 1:
            return particular_line.rsplit(None, 1)[-1].lower()

def first_word(particular_line):
    if particular_line != "\n": 
        particular_line = re.sub(ur'^\W*|\W*$', "",particular_line) 
        if len(particular_line) > 1:
            return particular_line.split(None, 1)[0].lower()

def chain(start, lines, depth):
    remaining = list(lines) 
    del remaining[remaining.index(start)]
    possibles = [x for x in remaining if (len(x.split()) > 2) and (first_word(x) == last_word(start))]
    maxchain = []
    for c in possibles:
        l = chain(c, remaining, depth)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write(str(depth) + " of " + str(len(all_lines)) + "   \r")
        sys.stdout.flush()
        if len(l) > len(maxchain):
            maxchain = l
            depth = str(depth) + "." + str(len(maxchain))
    return [start] + maxchain

#Start
final_output = []

#Finding the longest chain

for i in range (0, len(all_lines)):
    x = chain(all_lines[i], all_lines, i)
    if len(x) > 2:  
        final_output.append(x)
final_output.sort(key = len)

#Output on screen
print "\n\n--------------------------------------------"

if len(final_output) > 1: 
    print final_output[-1]
else: 
    print "Nothing found"
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of such lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
def matching_lines(line_pair):
    return line_pair[0].split()[-1].lower() == line_pair[1].split()[0].lower()

line_pairs = ((line,next_line) for line,next_line in itertools.izip(all_lines,all_lines[1:]))
grouped_pairs = itertools.groupby(line_pairs,matching_lines)
print max([len(list(y))+1 for x,y in grouped_pairs if x])
```

although im not sure it will be faster (but i *think* it will be since it only iterates one time and uses mostly builtins)

Comment: Nice solution. In Python 3.5 it needs to be `len(list(y))` as y is a generator. Also the total count is 1 short.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this code has the complexity of $O(n^2)$. It means that if your file has n lines, then the amount of iterations your code will perform is 1 * (n-1) for the first line, then 1 * (n-2) for the second line etc, with n such elements. For a big n, this is relatively equal to $n^2$. Actually, there's a bug in the code in this line

```
del remaining[remaining.index(start)]
```

where you probably meant to run this:

```
del remaining[:remaining.index(start)]
```

(notice the ':' in the square brackets) which expands the runtime (now you have (n-1) + (n-1) + .. + (n-1) = n*(n-1), which is slightly bigger then (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) ..).
Your can optimize the code as so: begin with maxchainlen = 0, curchainlen = 0. Now, iterate through the lines, every time compare the first word of the current line to the last word of the previous line. If they match, increase curchainlen by 1. If they don't, check if maxchainlen < curchainlen, if so, assign maxchainlen = curchainlen, and init curchainlen to 0. After you finish iterating through the lines, do this checkup for maxchainlen again. Example:

```
lw = last_word(lines[0])
curchainlen = 0
maxchainlen = 0
for l in lines[2:]:
    if lw = first_word(l):
        curchainlen = curchainlen + 1
    else:
        maxchainlen = max(maxchainlen, curchainlen)
        curchainlen = 0
maxchainlen = max(maxchainlen, curchainlen)
print(maxchainlen)
```

Comment: The new code has the complexity of O(n). So for long files, it will drastically enhance the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try splitting this job into two phases: first *finding* the chains and then comparing them.  That will simplify the code a lot.  Since chains will be a small subset of all the lines in the file, finding them first and then sorting them will be quicker than trying to process the whole thing in one big go.

The first part of the problem is a lot easier if you use the python `yield` keyword, which is similar to `return` but doesn't end a function.  This lets you loop over your content  one line at a time and process it in small bites without needing to hold the whole thing in memory at all times.

Here's a basic way to grab a file one line at a time. It uses `yield` to pull out the chains as it finds them

```
def get_chains(*lines):
    # these hold the last token and the
    # members of this chain
    previous = None
    accum = []

    # walk through the lines,
    # seeing if they can be added to the existing chain in `accum`
    for each_line in lines:
        # split the line into words, ignoring case & whitespace at the ends
        pieces = each_line.lower().strip().split(" ")
        if pieces[0] == previous:
            # match? add to accum
            accum.append(each_line)
        else:
            # no match? yield our chain
            # if it is not empty
            if accum:
                yield accum
                accum = []
        # update our idea of the last, and try the next line
        previous = pieces[-1]

    # at the end of the file we need to kick out anything
    # still in the accumulator
    if accum:
        yield accum
```

When you feed this function a string of lines, it will `yield` out chains if it finds them and then continue.  Whoever *calls* the function can capture the yielded chains and do things with them.

Once you've got the chains, it's easy to sort them by length and pick the longest.  Since Python has built-in list sorting, just collect a list of line-length -> line pairs and sort it.  The longest line will be the last item:

```
 def longest_chain(filename):

    with open (filename, 'rt') as file_handle:
         # if you loop over an open file, you'll get
         # back the lines in the file one at a time
        incoming_chains = get_chains(*file_handle)

        # collect the results into a list, keyed by lengths
        all_chains = [(len(chain), chain ) for chain in incoming_chains]
        if all_chains:
            all_chains.sort()
            length, lines = all_chains[-1]
            # found the longest chain
            return "\n".join(lines)
        else:
            # for some reason there are no chains of connected lines
            return  []
```