# Reorder array by their last letter starting with the first array and so on

Tags: javascript

So Im trying to create a function to reorder the array by their last letter starting with the first array and so on

The first array **TEAM** last letter **M** then it will find and match with the array that starts with letter **M** which is **MOIST** so letter **T** will match **TOKEN**

Example: ["team", "token", "moist"] to ["team", "moist", "token"]

Issue is im getting only the result of ["team", "moist"]

```
let array = ["team", "token", "moist"];
let newArr = [];

const reorderArr = () => {
// reorder array by their last letter starting with the first array and so on
console.log("ARRAY:", array);

array.forEach((arr, index) => {
   let currentWord = arr;
   console.log("LOOP: ", index);

if (!newArr.includes(currentWord)) {
  if (index === 0) {
    console.log("HIT ONCE");
    newArr.push(currentWord);
  } else {
    for (let x = 1; x < array.length; x++) {
      const nextWord = array[x];
      console.log("nextWord", nextWord);
      if (nextWord.slice(0, 1) === newArr[newArr.length - 1].slice(-1)) {
        console.log("HIT");
        newArr.push(nextWord);
      }
    }
  }
}
 });

console.log("REORDERED ARRAY:", newArr); // RESULT SHOULD BE ["team", "moist", "token"]
};

reorderArr();
```

Comment: Do you mean just sort by last letter? Or you mean match the first letter of one to the last letter of the previous?

Comment: @pilchard Kinda like that but from the first array TEAM last letter M then it will find and match with the array that starts with letter M which is MOIST then so on

Comment: That's not a trivial task, because you probably need backtracking mechanisms when you arrived in a dead end. Imagine `ab cb bd bc`. When you start with `ab` you have two choices `bd` and `bc` to continue, but only `bc` allows you finish your task and use all remaining words, whereas  by choosing `bd` you can't continue anymore and `bc` and `cb` are left over ... And this is only a trivial example.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at these questions (eventhough they use different languages) for some inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186976/longest-chain-of-last-word-of-line-first-word-of-next https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044854/checking-if-a-list-of-strings-can-be-chained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check all combinations with an array of left over words and an array of correct words.

```js
function reorder(array) {
    const
        check = (pool, result = []) => {
            if (!pool.length) return result;
            const last = result?.at(-1)?.at(-1);
            let longest = [];
            for (const word of pool) {
                if (last && last !== word[0]) continue;
                const temp = check(pool.filter(w => w !== word), [...result, word]);
                if (longest.length < temp.length) longest = temp;
            }
            return longest;
        };
    
    return check(array);
}

console.log(...reorder(["team", "token", "moist"]));
```